# Python GUI creating a list item with Text and checkboxes

Tags: python, list, user-interface, tkinter, tree

I am trying to create a list like in outlook. With list items with an layout like this:

[image]

Don't get me wrong this isn't a "give me the full answer" question. I just have the problem of the right naming. I would appreciate it a lot if some could throw in the right words and I will look for them by my own.

I used tkinter at the moment but in that it seems like there isn't a solution for that.

Kind regards.

Comment: Your problem description *"I am trying to create a list like in outlook. With list items with an layout like this"* is very vague. Where exactly do you have a problem? Please specify.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I work with Tkinter at the moment. I have created a Tree with multiple columns and I was also able to add an image to the first column. Now I try to add a checkbox to the second or third column. That were I failed and also cant find any (especially noob friendly) info about.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tkinter can do this by using a bit of object oriented programming you could define how one list element should look like and then with static variables you could define a position of a new line relative to the position of the previous line. Something like:

```
from tkinter import *

class Line:
    y = 0 # static variable for the y position
    def __init__(self):
        self.y_local = Line.y
        Line.y = Line.y + 40 # increase the static variable for the next line
        print(self.y_local)
    def draw(self, tk, h_line="Headline", a_info="Addtional Information", date="01/01/1970"):
        self.label_head = Label(text=h_line)
        self.label_head.place(x=20, y=self.y)
        self.label_info = Label(text=a_info)
        self.label_info.place(x=20, y=self.y+20)
        self.label_date = Label(text='Date')
        self.label_date.place(x=200, y=self.y)
        self.label_ndate = Label(text=date)
        self.label_ndate.place(x=200, y=self.y+20)
        self.chkbtn = Checkbutton(tk, text="Checkbox")
        self.chkbtn.place(x=300, y=self.y+20)


tk = Tk()
data = [
    ["News", "WWIII has been avoided", "02/04/2018"],
    ["Python", "Python solves 42 riddles", "02/04/2018"]
]
for line in data:
    temp = Line()
    temp.draw(tk, line[0], line[1], line[2])

mainloop()
```

Hope I understood your question well. That you have a list with information and want to display that in an easy and scalable way. I have not looked to add the lines around the information as I've never done that before I know there are separators I've used vertical once before but I wouldn't be surprised if you can draw a box around each line either.

Comment: The layout of this is exactly what I need, is it possible to add this as a row to a listbox or tree or anything like that? Thank you very much!

Comment: @K-Doe that is something I sadly don't know, edit: what do you plan to do with it, I'd guess you want to know which onces are checked and not?

Comment: I plan to do something like a to-do list. Maybe you use outlook. There you have these Flags at the end on each list item for "mark as done /undone" SO each item of my List should have one checkbox. To keep it compact I want to do that all in a list.